# Methods to connect to AWS Redshift through Python 3.x (Windows7) apart from using psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

Are there any other ways to connect to AWS Redshift through Python 3.x on Windows 7 - 64 bit platform, apart from using psycopg2?
Is psycopg2, the only library which we can use to connect to Redshift?

Comment: what is it that you are tring to do but cannot / what problems are you having with psycopg2?

Comment: I was trying to install psycopg2 on Python 3.7 on a Windows 64 bit platform. I was getting errors with libpq.lib file. I tried the easy install process but still the issue didnt get resolved. After some searches in google and StackOverflow, I found that, the latest stable version of psycopg2 (2.7.4) is not yet supported on Python 3.7. It is supported till 3.6

I downgraded my python to 3.6.5 in Anaconda and also to 2.7.15 through PyCharm. I was able to install psycopg2 in both and use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the available drivers on the postgres wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Python

There is one other driver supported on Windows, but in general `psycopg2` is your best bet.